# Differences in unilateral set

Tags: weightlifting, sets

I often see people doing unilateral exercises at the gym, but almost none of them do the same thing.

For instance, if someone wants to do X sets of Y reps of an exercise unilaterally, they can do :

- **Alternate reps**: *left, right, left, right,...* then pause, then repeat X times.
- **Alternate sets**: *left * Y, right * Y* then pause, then repeat X times
- **Alternate exercises**: *left * Y*, then pause, then repeat X times, then *right * Y* then pause, then repeat X times

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these 3 methods ? Is there any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the alternate reps or sets methods you mentioned is the best way to go because it is the most time efficient. I personally always go for the alternate sets, but I guess for stuff like biceps curls for example you could easily do alternate reps aswell.

Think about it, why would you do a set for, let's say your left arm but not for your right, then pause and after that train the right arm, which wasn't even trained before/had a long(er) pause (than needed). I'd say there is absolutly no benefit from the third option whatsoever.